# Getting AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute getText

Tags: python, function, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I have half-written a code to pull the titles and links from an RSS feed but it results in the above error. The error is in both the functions while getting the text. I want to strip the entered string of the title and link tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

def getlink(a):
    a= str(a)
    bsoup=BeautifulSoup(a)
    a=bsoup.find('link').getText()
    return a

def gettitle(b):
    b=str(b)
    bsoup=BeautifulSoup(b)
    b=bsoup.find('title').getText()
    return b

webpage= urllib.request.urlopen("http://feeds.feedburner.com/JohnnyWebber?format=xml").read()

soup=BeautifulSoup(webpage)
titlesoup=soup.findAll('title')
linksoup= soup.findAll('link')

for i,j in zip(titlesoup,linksoup):
    i = getlink(i)
    j= gettitle(j)

    print (i)
    print(j)
    print ("\n")
```

**EDIT**: *falsetru's method worked perfectly*.

I have one more question. Can text be extracted out of any tag by just doing `getText` ?

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i`, `j` is `title`, `link` already. Why do you find them again?

```
for i, j in zip(titlesoup, linksoup):
    print(i.getText())
    print(j.getText())
    print("\n")
```

Beside that, pass `features='xml'` to `BeautifulSoup` if you parse xml file.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, features='xml')
```

Answer (score 1):

I expect the problem is in

```
def getlink(a):
    ...
    a=bsoup.find('a').getText()
    ....
```

Remember find matches tag names, there is no `link` tag but an `a` tag. BeautifulSoup will return None from find if there is no matching tag, thus the NoneType error. Check the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) for details.

Edit:

If you really are looking for the text 'link' you can use `bsoup.find(text=re.compile('link'))`

Answer (score 0):

`b=bsoup.find('title')` returns `None`

try checking your input